# What is meant by "logical purity" in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, logic, logical-purity

What is meant by "logical purity" (in the context of Prolog programming)? The [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) tag info says *"programs using only Horn clauses"*, but then, how would predicates like [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) qualify, using as much as it does the cut, and the various meta-logical (what's the proper terminology? `var/1` and such) predicates, i.e. the low-level stuff.

I get it that it achieves some "pure" effect, but what does this mean, precisely?

For a more concrete illustration, please explain how does `if_/3` qualify as logically pure, seen in use e.g. [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30453357/849891)?

Comment: Good question, +1! Also check out the longer tag description for a bit more information: [logical-purity](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/logical-purity/info). Programs that use only Horn clauses definitely exhibit these properties.

Comment: @mat ah, you've edited it in the mean time! if you could maybe add an answer here, expanding some more about what is generalization and specialization, maybe with few examples, that would be great! (that's about using logvars in place of concrete data and vice-versa, correct?)

Comment: w.r.t logvars: My first reaction when I saw this word, was: What kind of logarithmic scheme is employed here?

Comment: @false huh! and I was trying to be more precise... :) wait, you didn't think of *"logging monads"*??...

Comment: And there is "logic variable" vs. "logical variable". Like "logic programming" which is translated to German into "logical programming" ...

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27907524/772868) is a related question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let us first get used to a *declarative* reading of logic programs.

Declaratively, a Prolog program states *what is true*.

For example

```
natural_number(0).
natural_number(s(X)) :-
        natural_number(X).
```

The first clause states: `0` is a natural number.

The second clause states: **If** `X` is a natural number, **then** `s(X)` is a natural number.

Let us now consider the effect of changes to this program. For example, what changes when we change the order of these two clauses?

```
natural_number(s(X)) :-
        natural_number(X).
natural_number(0).
```

Declaratively, exchanging the order of clauses does not change the intended meaning of the program in any way (disjunction is commutative).

*Operationally*, that is, taking into account the actual execution strategy of Prolog, different clause orders clearly often make a signifcant difference.

*However*, one extremely nice property of pure Prolog code is preserved regardless of chosen clause ordering:

> If a query `Q` *succeeds* with respect to a clause ordering `O1`, then
>   `Q` *does not fail* with a different ordering `O2`.

Note that I am *not* saying that `Q` always also *succeeds* with a different ordering: This is because the query may also *loop* or yield an error with different orderings.

For two queries `Q1` and `Q2`, we say that `G1` is *more general* iff it subsumes `G2` with respect to syntactic unification. For example, the query `?- parent_child(P, C).` is *more general* than the query `?- parent_child(0, s(0)).`.

Now, with pure Prolog programs, another extremely nice property holds:

> If a query `Q1` succeeds, then every more general query `Q2` *does not
>   fail*.

Note, again, that `Q2` may loop instead of succeeding.

Consider now the case of `var/1` which you mention, and think of the related predicate `nonvar/1`. Suppose we have:

```
my_pred(V) :-
        nonvar(V).
```

When does this hold? Clearly, it holds iff the argument is not a variable.

As expected, we get:

```
?- my_pred(a).
true.
```

However, for the *more general* query `?- my_pred(X).`, we get:

```
?- my_pred(X).
false.
```

Such a predicate is called *non-monotonic*, and you cannot treat it as a true relation due to this property: This is because the answer `false` above logically means that there are *no solutions whatsoever*, yet in the immediately preceding example, we see that there *is* a solution. So, illogically, a *more specific* query, built by *adding a constraint*, makes the query *succeed*:

```
?- X = a, my_pred(X).
true.
```

Thus, reasoning about such predicates is extremely complicated, to the point that it is no fun at all to program with them. It makes declarative debugging impossible, and hard to state any properties that are preserved. For instance, just swapping the order of subgoals in the above conjunctive query will make it fail:

```
?- my_pred(X), X = a.
false.
```

Hence, I strongly suggest to stay within the pure monotonic subset of Prolog, which allows the declarative reasoning along the lines outlined above.

CLP(FD) constraints, `dif/2` etc. are all *pure* in this sense: You cannot trick these predicates into giving logically invalid answers, no matter the modes, orders etc. in which you use them. `if_/3` also satisfies this property. On the other hand, `var/1`, `nonvar/1`, `integer/1`, `!/0`, predicates with side-effects etc. are all extra-logically referencing something outside the declarative world that is being described, and can thus not be considered pure.

**EDIT**: To clarify: The nice properties I mention here are in no way exhaustive. Pure Prolog code exhibits many other extremely valuable properties through which you can perceive the glory of logic programming. For example, in pure Prolog code, adding a clause can at most *extend*, never narrow, the set of solutions; adding a *goal* can at most *narrow*, never extend, it etc.

Using a single extra-logical primitive may, and typically will, already destroy many of these properties. Therefore, for example, every time you use `!/0`, consider it a *cut* right into the heart of purity, and try to feel regret and shame for wounding these properties.

A good Prolog book will at least begin to introduce or contain many hints to encourage such a declarative view, guide you to think about more general queries, properties that are preserved etc. Bad Prolog books will not say much about this and typically end up using exactly those impure language elements that destroy the language's most valuable and beautiful properties.

An awesome Prolog teaching environment that makes extensive use of these properties to implement declarative debugging is called [GUPU](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/gupu/), I highly recommend to check out these ideas. Ulrich Neumerkel has generously made one core idea that is used in his environment partly available as [library(diadem)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/diadem.pl). See the source file for a good example on how to declaratively debug a goal that fails unexpectedly: The library systematically builds generalizations of the query that *still* fail. This reasoning of course works perfectly *with pure code*.

Comment: I'm still reading, but, would't it be better if a Prolog chose an *optimistic* evaluation strategy for the subgoals (clauses, or what's the proper name - the child nodes of a search graph): execute all in parallel and pick one that completes the earliest! then there wouldn't be so much termination problems (re: *succeeds* vs. *does not fail*), and computational resources are supposed to be cheap these days.

Comment: thanks a bunch, this cleares things a lot! I've edited in a point from your tag wiki text, hope it's okay. :)  (i won't accept for a while, to draw in some more traffic, so people have a chance to upvote some more...)

Comment: @WillNess: What parallelism are you considering? OR- or AND-parallelism? If it is for OR-, then this does not help to improve universal termination at all, it may however, improve finding solutions, but enumerating them gets hard. As for AND-parallelism: This is in fact possible, but it only makes sense in programs with logical purity. OTOH: the **current** number of pure programs is very, very small and then this is often very costly.

Comment: @mat I notice you give "If a query Q1 succeeds, then every more general query Q2 does not fail." rule, but not its dual, which you give elsewhere (if it fails, its specialization must not succeed)? Also, maybe you have some links to sources for all this, where the monotonicity and generalization/specialization is described/defined?

Comment: To clarify why I am distinguishing *succeeds* and *does not fail*: There are several reasons why a program may not succeed, and one of them is a resource error (for example, insufficient RAM or CPU cores etc.), so also with additional resources and other search strategies, the distinction will be necessary. I have also added a bit more material to the post: Yes, the dual also holds in pure monotonic programs. I have clarified that the properties I list in the post are not exhaustive, they are only a few examples to give an idea of the declarative reasoning that pure Prolog code makes possible.

Comment: You say "disjunction is commutative", but clauses are in an implicit conjunction.