# Prolog and limitations of backtracking

Tags: prolog

This is probably the most trivial implementation of a function that returns the length of a list in Prolog

```
count([], 0).
count([_|B], T) :- count(B, U), T is U + 1.
```

one thing about Prolog that I still cannot wrap my head around is the flexibility of using variables as parameters.

So for example I can run `count([a, b, c], 3).` and get `true`. I can also run `count([a, b], X).` and get an answer `X = 2.`. Oddly (at least for me) is that I can also run `count(X, 3).` and get at least one result, which looks something like `X = [_G4337877, _G4337880, _G4337883] ;` before the interpreter disappears into an infinite loop. I can even run something truly "flexible" like `count(X, A).` and get `X = [], A = 0 ; X = [_G4369400], A = 1.`, which is obviously incomplete but somehow really nice.

Therefore my multifaceted question. Can I somehow explain to Prolog not to look beyond first result when executing `count(X, 3).`? Can I somehow make Prolog generate any number of solutions for `count(X, A).`? Is there a limitation of what kind of solutions I can generate? What is it about this specific predicate, that prevents me from generating all solutions for all possible kinds of queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is probably the most trivial implementation

Depends from viewpoint: consider

```
count(L,C) :- length(L,C).
```

Shorter and functional. And this one also works for your use case.

*edit*

library [CLP(FD)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd) allows for

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

count([], 0).
count([_|B], T) :- U #>= 0, T #= U + 1, count(B, U).

?- count(X,3).
X = [_G2327, _G2498, _G2669] ;
false.
```

*(further) answering to comments*

> It was clearly sarcasm

No, sorry for giving this impression. It was an attempt to give you a *synthetic* answer to your question. Every details of the implementation of length/2 - indeed much longer than your code - have been carefully weighted to give us a general and efficient building block.

> There must be some general concept

I would call (full) Prolog such general concept. From the very start, Prolog requires us to solve computational tasks *describing* relations among predicate arguments. Once we have *described* our relations, we can query our 'knowledge database', and Prolog attempts to enumerate *all* answers, in a *specific* order.

High level concepts like [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29) and [depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) (backtracking) are keys in this model.

Now, I think you're looking for *second order* constructs like [var](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=var/1)/1, that allow us to reason **about** our predicates. Such constructs cannot be written in (pure) Prolog, and a growing [school of thinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logical-purity) requires to avoid them, because are rather difficult to use. So I posted an alternative using CLP(FD), that effectively shields us in *some* situation. In this question specific context, it actually give us a simple and elegant solution.

> I am not trying to re-implement length

Well, I'm aware of this, but since count/2 *aliases* length/2, why not study the reference model ? ( see [source](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/boot/init.pl?show=src#length/2) on SWI-Prolog site )

Comment: @vasily: Is this really the answer you wanted?

Comment: @false absolutely not. It was clearly sarcasm, as the library implementation of length is most likely much longer than just 2 lines of code.

Comment: @CapelliC, sorry, but this is extremely cryptic for me. I am not trying to re-implement length, I am trying to understand why my primitive and blue-eyed implementation fails and what is it about my implementation that makes it "incomplete". There must be some general concept that describes what I am dealing here with.

Comment: @CapelliC, thank you for the explanation and the link to the purity topic. Indeed this one question is very much related to what I was asking about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941407/what-is-meant-by-logical-purity-in-prolog

Comment: @vasily: I say this without any irony or sacrasm: This is honestly one of the fastest learning curves I have seen on stackoverflow regarding Prolog. +1 for your observations and highly justified question and insightful answers by CapelliC and @tas!

Comment: @CapelliC: `var/1` is not second order. `call/N` is.

Comment: @false: sorry, IIRC var/1 was called the most fundamental, i.e. *simplest* metapredicate. So, should be second order, no ? Or it's possible to implement in pure Prolog ?

Comment: First order: variables for arguments. Second order: variables for predicates. `var/1` is as you say: meta-logical

Answer (score 4):

The answer you get for the query `count(X,3)` is actually not odd at all. You are asking which lists have a length of 3. And you get a list with 3 elements. The infinite loop appears because the variables B and U in the first goal of your recursive rule are unbound. You don't have anything before that goal that could fail. So it is always possible to follow the recursion. In the version of CapelliC you have 2 goals in the second rule before the recursion that fail if the second argument is smaller than 1. Maybe it becomes clearer if you consider this slightly altered version:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

count([], 0).
count([_|B], T) :-
    T #> 0,
    U #= T - 1,
    count(B, U).
```

Your query

```
?- count(X,3).
```

will not match the first rule but the second one and continue recursively until the second argument is 0. At that point the first rule will match and yield the result:

```
X = [_A,_B,_C] ?
```

The head of the second rule will also match but its first goal will fail because `T=0`:

```
X = [_A,_B,_C] ? ;
no
```

In your above version however Prolog will try the recursive goal of the second rule because of the unbound variables B and U and hence loop infinitely.

Comment: This also works without clpfd, no?
    count([], 0).
    count([_|B], T) :- T > 0, U is T - 1, count(B, U).

Comment: @Bezewy: no, try the most general query `?- count(List,Len).` It will crash on backtracking, should enumerate all solutions instead, as will do the CLP(FD) version.