# predicate encode in prolog

Tags: encoding, prolog

I'm new in prolog and I'm trying to write the predicate `encode(L,L1)` which counts the duplicates of elements in `L` ,for example:

```
encode([4,4,4,3,3],L).

L=[3,4,2,3].
```

This is what I have written:

```
encode(L,L1) :- encode(L,1,L1).

encode([],_,[]).      
encode([H],N,[N,H]).      
encode([H,H|T],N1,[N,H|T1]) :- M is N1+1, encode([H|T],M,[N,H|T1]).     
encode([H,Y|T],N,[N,H|T1]) :- H\=Y, encode([Y|T],T1).
```

The above predicate is not reversible. It only works if the first parameter is provided.

How can I write encode reversible?
For example:

```
encode(L,[3,4,2,3]).           
L = [4,4,4,3,3].
```

Comment: In place of `M is N1+1` try `M #= N1 + 1`. Make sure you load the CLP(FD) module (`:- use_module(library(clpfd)).`) And in place of `\=` use `\==`.

Comment: @lurker ,I tried the above but still after making the changes ,the problem remains : encode(L,[3,4,2,3]) does not give any answer (it throws exception "Out of local stack" ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your algorithm has a redundant counter in it. A little simplified would be:

```
encoded([], []).
encoded([X], [1,X]).
encoded([X,Y|T], [1,X|R]) :-
    dif(X, Y),
    encoded([Y|T], R).
encoded([X,X|T], [N,X|R]) :-
    N #> 1,
    N #= N1 + 1,
    encoded([X|T], [N1,X|R]).
```

Note in the last clause we need to ensure that `N` is greater than 1 as well.

Comment: @coder: note that even `encoded(Xs,[2,V]).` produces a perfect answer!

Comment: @coder: And even `encoded(Xs,[2,V,2,W]).`! Do you see the `dif` in the full answer?

Comment: @false ,thanks for the above notice.  One thing  I can't still understand is why use dif(X,Y) than X\==Y, I've tried both and both worked??

Comment: @coder: What should `V` and `W` be in the query `encoded(Xs,[2,V,2,W])`? They must be different. Thus `dif(V,W)` must be part of the answer. For, if they are identical, then it would be `[4,V]` and not `[2,V,2,W]`

Comment: @false: Yes but isn't the same thing  if we use \== instead (I understand that X,Y must not be identical ) ???

Comment: @coder `dif(X, Y)` and `X \== Y` do not have the same behavior. For example, try this at a prompt: `X \== Y, X = 1, Y = 1`. This will **succeed**. But, `dif(X, Y), X = 1, Y = 1` will **fail** (as it should, since `X` and `Y` are not different). So `dif/2` exhibitss [*logical purity*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941407/what-is-meant-by-logical-purity-in-prolog) but `\==/2` does not.