# Comparing elements from two lists of different sizes

Tags: prolog

Im learning Prolog and im trying to write a clause that check if one list (L1) is de result of duplicate other List(L2) N times,and return N as de result of checking how many times L2 is duplicated in L1. But I dont know how to compare the elements of two lists of different size and count how many times L2 is duplicated. Can you help me?.

Comment: Forget about Prolog and think: how would you do it by hand?

Comment: Looks like this could be your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67568087/method-that-counts-the-number-of-occurs-in-one-list-in-prolog

Answer (score 0):

One solution that comes to mind is using append/3. Since
append/3 is able to consume the beginning prefix of a list:

```
?- append([1,2],X,[1,2,3,5]).
X = [3, 5].
```

So a quite straight forwards solution does the following,
assuming the smaller list L2 and the bigger list L1 are given:

```
times(_, 0, []).
times(L2, M, L1) :- append(L2, H, L1), times(L2, N, H), M is N+1.
```

Seems to work:

```
?- times([a,b,c],X,[a,b,c,a,b,c]).
X = 2 ;
false.

?- times([a,b,c],X,[a,b,c,a,b,d]).
false.
```