# What is the difference between this two statements: a) p(1),!; b) p(1):-!;

Tags: prolog

What is the difference between this two statements:

a) `p(1),!`

b) `p(1):-!`

I came across this code:

```
p(1).
p(2):-!.
p(3).
```

What if I rewrite this as :

```
p(1).
p(2),!.
p(3).
```

Comment: The first one a) is part of a query, or RHS of a rule. The second one b) defines a rule.

Comment: Where did you come across this code? Either way, the first is correct Prolog, while the second is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking at a very simplistic example which makes it appear that there is a similarity or equivalence of behavior between `p(2) :- !` and `p(2), !`. It looks like they're both querying `p(2)`, and if successfully matching, moving on to the cut and truncating further backtracking. But that's not really how they both work.

The expression, `p(2) :- !.` is a predicate clause which defines a rule that says, *`p(2)` is true, and don't bother checking for other solutions*. When you make a query of the form `p(X)`, Prolog will try to find a fact or rule head which matches it. In this case, `p(2)` is a match and Prolog follows the rule. As a specific example, if you have:

```
p(2).
p(2).
```

And query:

```
| ?- p(X).
```

You get:

```
| ?- p(X).

X = 2 ? ;

X = 2

(1 ms) yes
| ?-
```

Whereas, if you have these fact

```
p(2) :- !.
p(2).
```

Then you get:

```
| ?- p(X).

X = 2

yes
| ?-
```

On the other hand, the expression `p(2), !.` syntactically cannot occur at the "top level" in Prolog. In other words, this is not legal Prolog:

```
p(2), !.
p(2).
```

If you try to do this, you'll get an error something like:

```
error: user:1: native code procedure (',')/2 cannot be redefined (ignored)
```

Prolog thinks you're trying to redefine the `,` operator. That's because the expression `p(2), !.` looks like:

```
','(p(2), !).   % Create a definition for ','
```

And it is true that `p(2) :- !` is known inside Prolog as the term, `':-'(p(2), !)` (`p(2)` being the *head* of the clause) which it treats specially at the top level. However, `p(2), !` syntactically needs to be part of a clause and not at the top level. In this context, the term `p(2)` is not the head of a clause that Prolog is attempting to match. Instead, it's a query which is part of another Predicate clause. For example:

```
% Define 'foo'
foo :- p(2), !.
foo.
```

If we query:

```
| ?- foo.

yes
| ?-
```

You see that it succeeds and, due to the cut, leaves no choice points after succeeding once. On the other hand, if we define:

```
foo :- p(2).
foo.
```

Then the query behaves differently:

```
| ?- foo.

true ? ;

yes
```

Here, `foo` succeeds and, due to lack of a cut and the additional `foo` clause/fact, leaves a choice point. We tell Prolog to go for more solutions (`;`) and we get one more, resulting in `yes`.

I said all that to show that these are very different contexts for two different operators: `,` and `:-`.

Comment: See this question, which has the same code in it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962835/prolog-differences-between-red-cut-and-green-cut

Comment: @Boris thanks for the cross-reference. Perhaps that's where the OP saw it as well. I decided to answer this particular question because I see that the OP has a fundamental misunderstanding of the semantics of a couple of different Prolog operators, although it it should be clear from a basic Prolog tutorial.

Comment: Sure, as they say, linked for "posterity"