# Cuts in a Prolog query?

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut

I have seen lots of examples of [cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(logic_programming)#:%7E:text=The%20cut%2C%20in%20Prolog%2C%20is,cut%20should%20be%20used%20sparingly.) used inside Prolog predicate clauses (removes all choicepoints of that specific predicate).

For example:

```
 gamble(X) :- gotmoney(X),!.
 gamble(X) :- gotcredit(X), \+ gotmoney(X).
```

However, how do they exactly behave when put inside a prolog query? They remove ALL choicepoints so far?

Comment: look at some other prolog cut questions, they may give you a better idea. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26483422/4437190 . https://stackoverflow.com/q/14541164/4437190.

Comment: There is no difference between a Prolog query and the body of a predicate, so your guess is essentially correct: none of the choice points before the cut will be backtracked to in order to satisfy the query. I prefer to think of it as committing to the bindings that have already been established.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Knowing when to use cut in prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541164/knowing-when-to-use-cut-in-prolog)